# Laravel 5.4 it is recommended to use "enable/disableForeignKeyConstraints()" by migrate:reset?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

My laravel 5.4 app contain complex database structure with many relations, so I'm willing to know it is ok to use `Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();` and `Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();` in `down()` function. Because if I run command *php artisan migrate:reset* then there are relations and delete is not possible...

Complete example:

```
public function down()
{
     Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
     Schema::drop('blog');
     Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

As described is this recommended to use because of Database functionality?

Comment: The problem is that down() can also be executed by a migrate:rollback; there's no guarantees that it is a migrate:reset where all/most tables are removed. Just write your migration to drop the related foreign keys instead.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would migrate your databases in a special order so there are no conflicts with foreign keys, e.g.
Create:

1. users
2. permissions
3. user_permission

When you want to do a rollback the best way is to reverse all your actions, so you start

Delete:

1. user_permission
2. permissions
3. users

A common mistake is this example:

```
class User extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username')->nullable()->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('user_permission', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users'); // error will be thrown, because user_permission still exists. 
        Schema::dropIfExists('user_permission');

    }
}
```

Of course you could use `disableForeignKeyConstraints`, but in my opinion it's a kind of dirty solution and you should follow the same way you migrated your tables (same way = don't disable foreign keys).

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid use case. This has been a big issue with laravel migrations from a long time. You need to make sure the order of drop tables works in such a way that it drops the related tables first before dropping the parent table. This can become very tedious with large number of migrations. Therefore forcing to disable foreign key constraints before dropping is valid. Although you need to be careful since you can drop individual migrations with existing relationship by mistake. This can cause big problems.

Laravel 5.5 is coming with a new command `migrate:fresh`. This would help with cleaning the database before migrating again unlike the existing `migrate:reset` or `migrate:refresh` which causes foreign key issues.